# Django CSS takes time to refresh

Tags: django

When I make a change in css, it takes time to be seen in browser. Often I just leave it and get back to do some backend stuff and while I'm doing that, suddenly and unexpectedly, the css changes are applied. I have seen some solutions on the internet, like clear browser's cache, but it doesn't work *every* time. What is the reason behind it? It gets annoying when you want immediate results.

Comment: you just save the changes in the IDE and refresh the browser using f5 or the reload button, working now?

Comment: CTRL F5 does not help?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I tried ctrl f5 but it doesn't do anything. I'm using Safari.

Comment: @mohammedqudah of course I tried to refresh the browser. I always do that. Is that even a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari for Mac's version of incognito mode is called Private Browsing. To turn it on, launch Safari and go to the Safari menu to Private Browsing. When you're done, go back to Safari > Private Browsing to disable it.